# Imagick svg to png not working with some SVGs

Tags: php, svg, imagick

I have implemented a converter to convert SVG images to PNG ones. It's working for some simple SVGs but it's not working for complex SVGs and the result will be a blank and white png file.

```
$svg = file_get_contents($pic);
$im = new Imagick();
$im->readImageBlob($svg);
$im->setImageFormat("png32");
$im->writeImage($filename.'.png');
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

The SVGs which cannot be converted are like the below SVG file:

```
<svg width="260" height="260" viewBox="0 0 260 260" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M100.429 189.572C93.2924 189.245 89.4157 188.047 86.8372 187.033C83.4205 185.692 80.9846 184.095 78.4204 181.513C75.8561 178.931 74.269 176.475 72.9459 173.03C71.9401 170.43 70.7525 166.521 70.428 159.325C70.0713 151.546 70 149.212 70 129.505C70 109.798 70.0785 107.468 70.4244 99.6824C70.749 92.4865 71.9437 88.5847 72.9423 85.9775C74.2726 82.5324 75.8597 80.0762 78.4168 77.4869C80.9775 74.9049 83.4134 73.301 86.8336 71.9668C89.4121 70.9527 93.2889 69.7552 100.425 69.4279C108.143 69.0719 110.461 69 129.998 69C149.542 69 151.853 69.0791 159.575 69.4279C166.711 69.7552 170.581 70.9599 173.166 71.9668C176.583 73.301 179.019 74.9049 181.583 77.4869C184.147 80.069 185.727 82.5288 187.058 85.9739C188.063 88.5739 189.251 92.4829 189.576 99.6788C189.929 107.465 190 109.795 190 129.502C190 149.202 189.929 151.539 189.576 159.325C189.251 166.521 188.056 170.43 187.058 173.03C185.727 176.475 184.144 178.931 181.583 181.513C179.022 184.095 176.583 185.692 173.166 187.033C170.588 188.047 166.711 189.245 159.575 189.572C151.86 189.928 149.542 190 129.998 190C110.461 190 108.143 189.932 100.429 189.572" fill="url(#paint0_radial)"/>
<path d="M100.429 189.572C93.2924 189.245 89.4157 188.047 86.8372 187.033C83.4205 185.692 80.9846 184.095 78.4204 181.513C75.8561 178.931 74.269 176.475 72.9459 173.03C71.9401 170.43 70.7525 166.521 70.428 159.325C70.0713 151.546 70 149.212 70 129.505C70 109.798 70.0785 107.468 70.4244 99.6824C70.749 92.4865 71.9437 88.5847 72.9423 85.9775C74.2726 82.5324 75.8597 80.0762 78.4168 77.4869C80.9775 74.9049 83.4134 73.301 86.8336 71.9668C89.4121 70.9527 93.2889 69.7552 100.425 69.4279C108.143 69.0719 110.461 69 129.998 69C149.542 69 151.853 69.0791 159.575 69.4279C166.711 69.7552 170.581 70.9599 173.166 71.9668C176.583 73.301 179.019 74.9049 181.583 77.4869C184.147 80.069 185.727 82.5288 187.058 85.9739C188.063 88.5739 189.251 92.4829 189.576 99.6788C189.929 107.465 190 109.795 190 129.502C190 149.202 189.929 151.539 189.576 159.325C189.251 166.521 188.056 170.43 187.058 173.03C185.727 176.475 184.144 178.931 181.583 181.513C179.022 184.095 176.583 185.692 173.166 187.033C170.588 188.047 166.711 189.245 159.575 189.572C151.86 189.928 149.542 190 129.998 190C110.461 190 108.143 189.932 100.429 189.572" fill="url(#paint1_radial)"/>
<path d="M115.267 129.758C115.267 121.483 121.918 114.773 130.125 114.773C138.332 114.773 144.986 121.483 144.986 129.758C144.986 138.033 138.332 144.743 130.125 144.743C121.918 144.743 115.267 138.033 115.267 129.758V129.758ZM107.233 129.758C107.233 142.506 117.482 152.84 130.125 152.84C142.768 152.84 153.016 142.506 153.016 129.758C153.016 117.009 142.768 106.675 130.125 106.675C117.482 106.675 107.234 117.009 107.234 129.758H107.233ZM148.573 105.76C148.573 106.827 148.886 107.87 149.474 108.758C150.061 109.645 150.896 110.337 151.874 110.745C152.851 111.154 153.927 111.261 154.964 111.053C156.002 110.846 156.956 110.332 157.704 109.578C158.453 108.824 158.963 107.863 159.169 106.817C159.376 105.771 159.271 104.686 158.866 103.7C158.462 102.714 157.776 101.872 156.897 101.278C156.017 100.685 154.983 100.369 153.925 100.368H153.923C152.505 100.369 151.145 100.937 150.142 101.948C149.139 102.959 148.574 104.33 148.573 105.76V105.76ZM112.114 166.348C107.768 166.148 105.405 165.418 103.836 164.802C101.754 163.985 100.269 163.011 98.7077 161.439C97.1463 159.867 96.1798 158.371 95.3731 156.272C94.7611 154.69 94.0371 152.307 93.8395 147.924C93.6234 143.186 93.5802 141.763 93.5802 129.758C93.5802 117.754 93.6269 116.335 93.8395 111.593C94.0374 107.21 94.7668 104.832 95.3731 103.245C96.1834 101.146 97.1484 99.6486 98.7077 98.0742C100.267 96.4998 101.751 95.5253 103.836 94.7118C105.405 94.0947 107.768 93.3647 112.114 93.1655C116.813 92.9475 118.225 92.904 130.125 92.904C142.025 92.904 143.438 92.9504 148.141 93.1662C152.487 93.3658 154.846 94.1012 156.419 94.7125C158.501 95.526 159.986 96.5027 161.547 98.0749C163.109 99.6472 164.072 101.147 164.882 103.245C165.494 104.828 166.218 107.211 166.415 111.593C166.632 116.335 166.675 117.755 166.675 129.759C166.675 141.764 166.632 143.183 166.415 147.925C166.217 152.308 165.49 154.69 164.882 156.273C164.072 158.372 163.106 159.869 161.547 161.44C159.988 163.011 158.501 163.985 156.419 164.802C154.85 165.419 152.487 166.149 148.141 166.349C143.442 166.567 142.03 166.61 130.125 166.61C118.22 166.61 116.812 166.567 112.114 166.349V166.348ZM111.745 85.0781C106.999 85.296 103.756 86.0548 100.924 87.166C97.993 88.3135 95.5082 89.853 93.0271 92.3509C90.5459 94.8488 89.023 97.3546 87.885 100.314C86.783 103.171 86.0304 106.44 85.8143 111.225C85.5946 116.018 85.5443 117.55 85.5443 129.758C85.5443 141.965 85.5946 143.498 85.8143 148.291C86.0304 153.076 86.783 156.344 87.885 159.202C89.023 162.157 90.5463 164.668 93.0271 167.165C95.5079 169.661 97.9894 171.199 100.924 172.35C103.762 173.461 106.999 174.22 111.745 174.437C116.501 174.655 118.018 174.71 130.125 174.71C142.231 174.71 143.751 174.659 148.504 174.437C153.251 174.22 156.491 173.461 159.325 172.35C162.257 171.199 164.741 169.662 167.223 167.165C169.704 164.667 171.223 162.157 172.365 159.202C173.467 156.344 174.223 153.076 174.435 148.291C174.651 143.494 174.702 141.965 174.702 129.758C174.702 117.55 174.651 116.018 174.435 111.225C174.219 106.439 173.467 103.17 172.365 100.314C171.223 97.3582 169.7 94.8528 167.223 92.3509C164.745 89.8491 162.257 88.3135 159.329 87.166C156.491 86.0548 153.25 85.2924 148.508 85.0781C143.754 84.8591 142.235 84.8058 130.13 84.8058C118.025 84.8058 116.503 84.8565 111.747 85.0781" fill="white"/>
<defs>
<radialGradient id="paint0_radial" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(77.7663 187.349) scale(152.355 153.625)">
<stop offset="0.09" stop-color="#FA8F21"/>
<stop offset="0.78" stop-color="#D82D7E"/>
</radialGradient>
<radialGradient id="paint1_radial" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(153.12 183.464) scale(134.074 135.192)">
<stop offset="0.64" stop-color="#8C3AAA" stop-opacity="0"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#8C3AAA"/>
</radialGradient>
</defs>
</svg>
```

For more information, when I want to convert it also via command line it says something like the below:

```
convert-im6.q16: unrecognized color `paint0_radial' @ warning/color.c/GetColorCompliance/1052.
convert-im6.q16: non-conforming drawing primitive definition `fill' @ error/draw.c/RenderMVGContent/4301.
```

Comment: Maybe inkscape needs it reordered so the gradients are first.

Comment: @RobertLongson could you please explain more?

Comment: Whats unclear? The gradients are defined after they are used.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks, what should I do to handle this kind of problem programmatically? I uploaded this SVG file to some online SVG converter and they were okay with it.

Comment: Write a program to swap the order.